# Android constraint textview adjacent/tail to another textview breaks UI

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have been working on constraint layout for a while. There a requirement in which i had to constraint textview1 to another adjacent textview2. Textview1 does not have a fixed length, once the Textview1 grows it pushes my textview2 out of the screen

This is the xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="this is long text this is long text this is long text this"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You could also check the screenshot for the same[image: In this image the purple color is Textview1 and Textview2 is constraint to the endOf Textview1]

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the second TextView gets pushed out of the screen is that Views with `wrap_content`, by default, do not respect their constraints when there is not enough space to satisfy them. You need to explicitly set `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` for the first TextView to enforce its constraints in such case.

Secondly, to have the right TextView stick to the left one, you need to put them in a packed horizontal chain with a bias of 0. Add `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` to the second TextView to create a valid chain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="this is long text this is long text this is long text this"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid pushing the other view out of the screen don't use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

You can use `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.x"` to tell your view to be equal to some percentage of the screen in width.

**For example, put this in your constraintLayout:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="this is long text this is long text this is long text thisthis is long text this is long text this is long text thisthis is long text this is long text this is long text this"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2" />
```

**It will look like this:**
[image]

And if you want to enable your textView to expand just remove `android:maxLines="1"`

Comment: This is a good solution, but according to my requirement the left textview should grow bigger and once the second textview has reached the right end of the screen the first textview should stop growing instead have '...' at the end